# Reading/Writing Hex Bytes from/to a Binary File

Tags: c++, stl, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I need to read the file in binary mode and store the bytes as hex values in any STL container (preferably std::list). Later I need to write them back to a file, also in binary mode. So, I declared,

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

std::ifstream File("File_Name", std::ios::binary);

std::list<BYTE> File_Bytes;
```

With all the searching, I understood a couple of things. Reading can be done with std::istream::read() or std::istreambuf_iterator (I could be very much wrong. Please correct me.) and the read() function only takes char* as argument for stored bytes in memory and size of the input stream.

How would I do this where I have to read the bytes from the file into the BYTE list and again similarly write from the BYTE list to the file using istream and ostream respectively? Please clarify this for me. Thanks.

Note: This is actually for a Huffman encoder/decoder where I need to compress and decompress within the program internally and write the decompressed bits as output file. This is to verify the losslessness of the compression and the correctness of the program. Additionally, can anyone also tell me how I would write the encoded binary bits to a file and also what file extension would the encoded Huffman file have? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you prefer std::list?

Comment: Take a look at this: [reading file into vector using iterators[(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795326/using-insert-iterators-when-reading-from-file)

Comment: @laser_wizard std::list has random access, which kinda helped me in other problems. I know files are written sequentially, but std::list kinda became my staple preference. I know we have to change according to what suits best for the program, but this worked for me in most cases, so I use it. Why do you ask? Is it not suitable in this case?

Comment: Am I right in thinking you wish to read a *whole* file into a container and also write a whole file with the contents of a container?

Comment: @MikeKinghan Yeah, that's exactly what I have to do. I have to read an entire file, encode it using Huffman algorithm and write all byte encodings in sequential byte order, thereby 'compressing' it.

Comment: `list` is probably the single worst choice of the sequential containers; since it's a doubly-linked list you could use 17 bytes of ram for every 1 byte of data in the file (and probably much more depending on the allocator).   Also it isn't random-access; only forward and back.  `vector` and `deque`  are better for random access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As clarified by comments, you want to load the bytes of a binary file into
some STL container of `char` - or more accurately, `uint8_t` - and 
to save such a container back to a binary file.

There are many ways to do this, including as you have discovered, the use
of [`std::basic_istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) 
and [`std::basic_ostream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write), 
or [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) 
and [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator).

The latter approach yields the much simplest code. The `fread`/`fwrite` approach
yields the fastest code, but simpler is better for what are evidently
going to be merely prologue and epilogue operations of your program.

Here is a matching pair of template functions that will respectively:

Return an STL container of the parameter type `Container`, populated with
the byte-sequence of an input file.

Copy the elements of an STL container of the parameter type `Container` to a
byte-sequence in an output file.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdint>

template<class Container>
Container binary_load(std::string const & bin_file_name)
{
    std::ifstream in(bin_file_name,std::ios::binary);
    if (!in) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not open \"" + bin_file_name + 
            "\" for reading");
    }
    std::noskipws(in); // PON 1
    return Container(std::istream_iterator<std::uint8_t>(in),
                        std::istream_iterator<std::uint8_t>()); //PON 2

}

template<class Container>
void binary_save(Container && data, std::string const & bin_file_name)
{
    std::ofstream out(bin_file_name,std::ios::binary);
    if (!out) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not open \"" + bin_file_name + 
            "\" for writing");
    }
    std::copy(data.begin(),data.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::uint8_t>(out,"")); // PON 3  
}
```

To compile an elementary use case, append this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string infile = argv[1];
    string outfile = infile + ".saved";
    auto data(binary_load<vector<std::uint8_t>>(infile));
    binary_save(data,outfile);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles as C++11 or better. The resulting program loads the file that you specify as its first
commandline argument into an `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` and then just
saves that vector into a file of the same name with the additional
extension `.saved`. Your program, of course, will load one vector
and save a different one.

Points Of Note (PON):

1. This statement is needful to inform the stream `in` that
   it should extract *all* bytes, and not skip whitespace bytes.
2. This statement directly constructs the populated `Container` from a `[begin,end)`
   iterator range, in the way that every STL container can be constructed.
   The `begin` iterator `std::istream_iterator<char>(in)` is the *start-of-stream*
   iterator for `in`, and the `end` iterator `std::istream_iterator<char>()`
   is the *end-of-stream* iterator for every stream.
3. This statement copies the byte sequence to successive positions of an
   `std::ostream_iterator<char>` initially positioned at the start of `out`.
   The `""` argument of the iterator's constructor informs it that the
   empty string (i.e. nothing) shall separate the successive output bytes.

These function templates have somewhat more generality than you strictly 
require:

- The `Container` type with which you invoke `binary_load` need not be
  a container of `uint8_t` or even of a type of the same size. It need
  only be a container type that can be constructed from an iterator range over a 
  sequence of `uint8_t`.
- Likewise the `Container` type which you invoke `binary_save` need
  only be one whose elements are of a type `E` that is implicitly
  convertible to `uint8_t`, with the caveat that truncation would occur
  if you waywardly chose to save any `E`s that were not representable in `uint8_t`.

So putting these together, no harm is done, for example, if you
replace `vector<uint8_t>` with `vector<long>` in the example program.

Of course, if you mistakenly invoked either function template with a 
container type that did not satisfy the template's requirements of 
`Container`, the code would not compile.

**Continued for OP's comments**

> Can I use unsigned char instead [of uint8_t]?

Yes, `uint8_t` is almost inevitably defined as `unsigned char` by your
compiler(s), and any 8-bit type integral type will do. `uint8_t` just
most clearly says "byte". If you wished
to further parameterize the template functions with respect to the "byte"
type, you could do so like:

```
...
#include <type_traits>

template<class Container, typename Byte = std::uint8_t>
Container binary_load(std::string const & bin_file_name) {

    static_assert(sizeof(Byte) == 1,"Size of `Byte` must be 1");

    // `std::uint8_t` becomes `Byte` 
    ...
}

template<class Container, typename Byte = std::uint8_t>
void binary_save(Container && data, std::string const & bin_file_name) {

    static_assert(sizeof(Byte) == 1,"Size of `Byte` must be 1");
    // `std::uint8_t` becomes `Byte` 
    ...
}
```

Regarding the right file extension for Huffman encoded files, there is no
defacto standard. Choose what you like.

And unless you are required to use MS VC10 (with patchy C++11 support)
for your console version there no need to. [Bang up-to-date GCC toolchains
are freely available for Windows](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/),and
supporting IDEs: [CodeLite](http://codelite.org/),[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

Comment: Oh my god, Mike Kinghan, Thank you so much! When you asked me about my problem, I didn't expect you would give me an explanation with such clarity and such detail. I understood everything you explained very clearly. I compiled the code and it works like a charm. Thank you very much once again. Kudos to you! :-)

Comment: @WDRKKS Answer updated for comments since deleted. If this answer solves your problem you can [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Then it no longer appears to be unanswered; you get some SO reputation points, and so do I.

Comment: Yes, I will accept the answer. Thank you very much for your help and the extra information. I'm really learning a lot today. I've got one more last doubt, though. I used a for loop to print out all the "bytes" in the `vector` from begin to end, and compare it with the file opened in a hex editor. I noticed that the bytes are not in the same order in the output window as in the hex editor. Why is that so? Can you please tell me. I did use the right method to print it in the correct format (hex, binary, integer, etc.).

Comment: **Edit:** I compared it more closely, it checks out. Thank you very much once again, Mr. Kinghan. I accepted your answer. Thumbs up to you. :-)

Comment: @WDRKKS You're welcome. The easiest and conclusive way to test the example programis to use a binary-diff tool, such as [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) to compare the input and output files, using some `zip` files or image/music files as test data. I already did, of course. Incidentally the `std::enable_if` foot-note was ill-advised. The answer is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using fixed sized buffers of `uint8_t`:

```
const unsigned int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024*1024;  
uint8_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
// ...
my_file.read((char *)buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

In your program, you would read a buffer, process it, then read another buffer from the input.

The array is a more efficient container than `std::vector` or `std::list` for your purposes.

Also, use `uint8_t` because it's a standardized type.

Comment: What happens if the file is greater then 1024^2? Proper use of containers can make code much easier to write and read. `std::vector::resize()` can avoid the costly grow/copy associated with most container performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your question touches on two very different topics.

1. How do I read & write a binary file
2. How do I manipulate binary data. (inflate/deflate)

**File IO**

Two popular methods for reading files is `read()` and `getline()`. I use `read()` when dealing with binary files and `getline()` when reading texts files per line. Since you're dealing with binary data I would suggest using `read()`.

```
// Open Binary file at the end
std::ifstream input(filePath, std::ios::ate | std::ios::binary);
assert(input.is_open());

// Calculate size
size_t end = input.tellg();
input.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
size_t beg = input.tellg();
size_t len = end - beg;
assert(len > 0);

// Read in Binary data
std::vector<char> binaryData(len);
input.read(&(binaryData[0]),len);

// Close
input.close();
```

At this stage of the game you have all of your binary data stored in a vector. I know in your example you had expressed using a `list` instead, but given that you want to deal with a continuous stream of bytes a `vector` seems more inline with what you were doing.

**Binary**

There are a few ways to deal with binary data. You can use the trusty shift operators `<<` and `>>` coupled with some good and `&` and or `|` logic. However, if you want a more visual representation in your code I would suggest looking into `std::bitset`.

Using a bitset you can easily load the content of your `vector` into an 8-bit representation in binary.

```
std::bitset<8>  deflatedBinary(binaryData[0]);
std::bitset<12> inflatedBinary;
```

The first `bitset` holds the 8-bit binary representation for your first `char` and the second set, inflatedBinary, has twelve bits all zeroed out. From here you can access their elements through indexing `[]`. You can read more about `std::bitset` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/).

Comment: Thanks for the information, Freddy. Although, I have a couple of questions. Firstly, you made a vector of type char. This can be used to declare even for type unsigned char (BYTE), right? Silly question, but making sure. Secondly, the binary data in my program is stored in a std::vector<bool>. And the program instructions page insists on using bit operators like you also suggested. Can I use this vector along with those operators? Please clarify this for me. Thanks.

Comment: I used `char`, but could have just as easily used `unsigned char`. In all honesty Thomas Matthews  has a better approach in using an `uint_8` since its size is guaranteed to be 1 byte. My code makes a dangerous assumption that char/unsigned char is always 1byte which for some machines isn't the case. To your second question,  `std::vector` is just a container, you don't want to perform bit operators on it. Sounds like your professor wants you to use the true/false `bool` in the container as if it was binary.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that. I read up on `std::bitset` and noticed that you used bitset to put the same bytes read from the file as binary data. I should have been more clear with my question. By binary data, I meant the Huffman encoded values pertaining to each byte where the length of each value is variable because it's based on byte frequency. I see that `std::bitset` length is constant and empty bits are filled with zero. This will change the encoded values. Is there a workaround to this? If not, `std::vector<bool>` works pretty well for `std::strings`. It might work well with bytes too.